# Use Controllers from one MVC project in another MVC project, same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Here's the scenario:

I have a nopCommerce MVC website - I need to "open up" the data in this site to other sites via a webservice. I'm very new to MVC btw.

My plan is to create a webApi project in the same solution of the nopCommerce site and reference it. Then, in the webAPI controllers access the nopCommerce controllers e.g.

```
var product = Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogueController.GetProduct(id);
```

I can't do this because I have to instantiate a CatalogController object - I started to create the object but there's so much that needs to be passed in to instantiate it - dozens of services, so this part has thrown me - I'm not sure how these Controllers are created in the "standard" MVC project - I can't find it anywhere so I assume it's under the hood somewhere...?

My question - is it possible to even do what I would like to do - the aim is to not duplicate the code in the nopCommerce project - I just want to leave that project as is and use the functions that already exist in it by calling them from the web service - perhaps my idea on how to do it is flawed/not possible? Can you suggest alternative ways of doing it? or explain how I can create the controller?

Comment: You should be referencing the services and not attempting to call the controllers.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how I should do this?

Answer (score 1):

While this can be done, it's definitely not a recommended approach. In a traditional scenario, what I would suggest is to move the code from your MVC actions that you want to reuse into a class library that both your MVC and Web Api projects could share. However, given that you're dealing with a third-party solution here, nopCommerce, I'm not sure how much code is actually available for you to shuffle. I'm not familiar with nopCommerce, but if there's any underlying API that you have access to, like repository or service classes that it provides, I would suggest having your Web Api utilize those rather than the controller actions directly.

Comment: thanks for the info. I'll check to see if there are any service classes I can use.